# Java - ant cannot find rt.jar

Tags: jar, path, java

I'm compiling DrJava by following [these](http://pastebin.com/gZ8q8YHj) instructions.

But when I run `ant jar`, I get the error:

`/Users/arthur/dj/drjava/build.xml:1270: Can't find rt.jar in the Java 7 home: ${env.JAVA7_HOME}`

I know that `rt.jar` is in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib`.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is same as what others have provided - just a little more detailed. So what you simply need is type this on your shell:

```
export JAVA7_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib
```

Now you have mentioned **I know that rt.jar is in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib.**

Usually you would not have `Contents/Home` inside JDK. A standard Java installation should have `jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/jre/lib`. Check if you have provided the correct path above and rt.jar is indeed in there.

Comment: Now I get `Can't find rt.jar in the Java 7 home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk`

Comment: And now it's `Can't find rt.jar in the Java 7 home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib`

Comment: edited the answer again. you need to check the original details you have given. Either the path provided is incorrect or the rt.jar is not in there.

Comment: have double checked. That is the path. I copied it from Get Info.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you point ant to a JDK rather than to a JRE.

Comment: The error message says "the Java 7 home: ${env.JAVA7_HOME}". The JAVA7_HOME environment variable should point to your JDK.

Answer (score 1):

SET PATH TO JDK..This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. Pulak was close, but not quite right: you don't need the `jre/lib` part at the end. The command that ultimately did the trick for me was:

```
export JAVA7_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/
```